# Кожу́х или ко́жух?

Tags: орфоэпия

Чаще, когда говорят об одежде типа дубленки, ударение ставят так ― **кожу́х**, а о покрытии механизма — **ко́жух**. А как же правильно?

Answer (score 2):

Согласна, что **кожу́х** во всех значениях. Только ко́жух не жаргонизм, а просторечие.
Одежда:
кожУх, кожухИ,
кожухА, кожухОв,
кожухУ, кожухАм,
кожУх, кожухИ,
кожухОм, кожухАми,
о кожухЕ, о кожухАх

А профессионализм **кожу́х** (футляр, покрытие) склоняется несколько по-другому:
И. кожу́х (ед.ч),   кожуха́ (мн.ч)
Р. кожу́ха,         кожухо́в
Д. кожу́ху,             кожуха́м
В. кожу́х,          кожуха́
Т. кожу́хом,        кожуха́ми
П. о кожу́хе,            кожуха́х

Comment: Я имел в виду именно профессионализм.   
Профессиональный технический жаргон тем не менее вполне себе жаргон.  
КОжух (футляр, покрышка) я оьношу именно к профессиональному жаргону. 

В отношении же КожУх-кожухА-кожухУ и т.д. то это никакой не "профессионализм", а обычная нормативная парадигма.

Comment: Я про то и говорю, что профессионализм тоже кожУх,но во множ.ч. кожухА; в Р.- кожУха,Т.- кожУхом. А кОжух - просторечие, употребляется только в устной речи.Возможно, тоже будет нормой, но пока нет.Вы же себе противоречите, сами написали, что в обоих значениях кожУх,а потом добавили про технич.жаргонизм.Непоследовательно.

Answer (score 0):

КожУх в обоих значениях. КОжух - жаргонизм (технический).