# Слово «кожух» во множественном числе

Tags: морфология, орфоэпия, множественное-число

Как будет "кожух" во множественном числе?

Comment: Есть противоречащие друг другу источники? Приведите их.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [КожУх или кОжух?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/14330/%d0%9a%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%a3%d1%85-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%9e%d0%b6%d1%83%d1%85)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Слово *кожу́х* во множественном числе в именительном падеже звучит как *кожухи́*, в родительном — *кожухо́в*. Варианты *ко́жух, кожуха́* не рекомендуются.

Источник — «Орфоэпический словарь русского языка» под ред. Н. А. Еськовой.